# Using OpenGL in InputMethod service

Tags: animation, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, android-input-method

I'm developing a concept-keyboard and I need to drop animated shadows on keys.

**It is possible to use OpenGL ES while subclassing `InputMethodService`?**

If I'd use a `GLSurfaceView` in `onCreateInputView`, will it conflict with the current visible activity if it uses OpenGL ES too?
Can be `GLSurfaceView` totally avoided by drawing offscreen?
Does Android support the use of multiple OpenGL ES contexts on different, but concurrent, activity?

I need Android 2.2 compatibility, so solutions like `TextureView` are not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody think this question deserve an answer or simply understood the possible issue, I did it myself.

I created a test activity which use a `GlSurfaceView` with some simple fragment shader and an `EditText`. 
Then I edited the *SoftKeyboard* sample from Android SDK to make it use a `GlSurfaceView` with another simple shader.

The test consists in launching the test activity and use the altered *SoftKeyboard* to type into the text box.

On Android 4.2 this works and both `GlSurfaceView` are rendered.
On Android 2.3.3 this fails with this errors:

`E/SurfaceFlinger(1556): createNormalSurfaceLocked() failed (Invalid argument)

W/WindowManager(1556): OutOfResourcesException creating surface

I/WindowManager(1556): Out of memory for surface!  Looking for leaks...

W/WindowManager(1556): No leaked surfaces; killing applicatons!

W/ActivityManager(1556): Killing processes Free memory at adjustment 1`

I was aware that the concurrency use of the video hardware (and its driver) may cause incompatibility but I'm not sure if this is due to the inability of early Android version to handle multiple OpenGL ES context or something else (memory amount, hardware, driver, ...)

One could investigate with NDK.

Comment: If you're happy with the results of your research so far, you can *accept* your answer with the green tick on the left.

Comment: I'd like to keep this as an open question. I'm quite busy right now but maybe I'll make some more test someday and definitely close.